# Stuck wth issue: nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Trying to integrate JPA hibernate and SpringBoot

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
10:49:55,001 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2178) Application startup failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) [spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:156) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:136) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-1.5.15.RELEASE.jar:1.5.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
```

My Entity class

```
 import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class ApiConfig  {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name="KEY")
    private Long key;

    @Column(name="SERVICE_NAME")
    private String serviceName;

    @Column(name="CLIENT_ID")
    private String clientId;
    @Column(name="APP_NAME")
    private String appName;
    @Column(name="RPA_NAME")
    private String rpaName;
    @Column(name="TRANSACTION_NAME")
    private String transactionName;
    @Column(name="ACTIVE")
    private String active;
    @Column(name="START_DATE")
    private Date startDate;
    @Column(name="UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date updatedDate;
    public Long getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(Long key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public String getServiceName() {
        return serviceName;
    }
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }
    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }
    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }
    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }
    public String getRpaName() {
        return rpaName;
    }
    public void setRpaName(String rpaName) {
        this.rpaName = rpaName;
    }

    public String getTransactionName() {
        return transactionName;
    }
    public void setTransactionName(String transactionName) {
        this.transactionName = transactionName;
    }
    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Date getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }
    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@zld02392.pp.tt.com:1524:d23233
spring.datasource.username=new
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My @Repository class

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.att.first.ordermanagementautomation.jpa.entity.ApiConfig;

@Repository
public interface IApiConfigRepo extends JpaRepository<ApiConfig,Long>{

}
```

Comment: check your jpa repository

Comment: Is that the full stack? Likely a dependency clash

Comment: jpa repository seems to be proper for me. Can you please guide me

Comment: springboot and hibernate integartion.

Comment: Are you running the application from an executable jar or attempting to deploy onto a server? Can you please provide the results of your maven/gradle dependency tree?

Comment: Do you have hibernate-entitymanager and hibernate-core added as part of dependency. I got this error when i dinn't had them or when the jar was corrupted.

Comment: Hi Ben, trying to deploy it to JBOSS server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jboss logging error while deploying springboot application in jboss server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759651/jboss-logging-error-while-deploying-springboot-application-in-jboss-server)

Comment: Please don't post questions twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759651/jboss-logging-error-while-deploying-springboot-application-in-jboss-server