# Jboss logging error while deploying springboot application in jboss server

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jboss, jboss-logging

22:40:03,522 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2265) Application startup failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Even tried to remove the jboss-logging

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version ob JBoss are you using?

Comment: Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.4.7.GA

Comment: That's EAP right?

Comment: Yup,absolutely.

Comment: and what's your spring boot version?

Comment: spring boot : 1.5.15

Comment: Thumb question. Why do you use JBoss when you have Spring Boot?

Comment: Dude, client wants it in jboss server. are you aware of this issue?

Comment: Yes. run maven dependency:analyze-report and post the report here

Comment: and please don't post the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51752888/stuck-wth-issue-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck wth issue: nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51752888/stuck-wth-issue-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-jboss-logg)